# Upgraded to Spring Security 4 and now I'm unable to login

Tags: spring, spring-security, csrf, spring-security4

I just upgraded to Spring Security 4.2.3.RELEASE and now I can't login.  Specifically, when I login, submitting these parameters

```
OWASP_CSRFTOKEN ZLCK-J3VV-OJTK-8GZW-H68V-C8N6-CE6G-U6AQ
j_password aaa
j_username mouser
```

I get the error

```
Could not verify the provided CSRF token because your session was not found.
```

You can clearly see from the above it is there.  Below is my Spring security configuration.  What else do I need to check to get this working?

```
<beans:bean id="mycoUsernamePasswordUrlAuthenticationFilter"
    class="org.collegeboard.myco.core.security.mycoUsernamePasswordUrlAuthenticationFilter">
    <beans:property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/j_spring_security_check" />
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    <beans:property name="authenticationFailureHandler">
        <beans:bean
            class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler">
            <beans:property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/login/failure" />
            <beans:property name="exceptionMappings" ref="exceptionMappings" />
        </beans:bean>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="authenticationSuccessHandler">
        <beans:bean
            class="org.collegeboard.myco.security.mycoAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
            <beans:property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/authenticate" />
            <beans:property name="sessionService" ref="sessionService" />
        </beans:bean>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean> 

...     
<beans:bean id="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <beans:constructor-arg name="loginFormUrl" value="/login" />
</beans:bean>


<http name="defaultSecurity" security-context-repository-ref="mycoSecurityContextRepository"
    auto-config="false" use-expressions="true" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager"
    entry-point-ref="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <!-- <access-denied-handler error-page="/denied"/> -->
    <custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"
        ref="mycoUsernamePasswordUrlAuthenticationFilter" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/lti/launch" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/status" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/termsOfUse" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/privacyPolicy" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/contactUs" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/legal" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="permitAll" />
...
    <intercept-url pattern="/dwrsetcookie" access="isFullyAuthenticated()" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/dwrpageid" access="permitAll" />
    <logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/logout" logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout" />
</http>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager" id="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="sbdUserDetailsService">
        <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder" />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add the below CSRF input to your login jsp,

```
<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"value="${_csrf.token}"/>
```

Or disable CSRF by adding the below to http tag

```
<csrf disabled="true"/>
```